# Both states are getting updated only after the second event call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have 2 functions. One is getting called when I type on the search input. The second one is getting called when I select a category. Default value for search is '' and for selectedCategories null. However when I type first time or click category first time. First time the functions are getting called with the default values of both states. It looks like I am always 1 step before the right one.

```
const onTextChanged = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            setIsComponentVisible(true);
            setSearch(value);
        };
    
        const selectCategory = async (category) => {
            const { id } = category;
            if (!selectedCategories || !selectedCategories[id]) {
                setCategories((prevState: any) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    [id]: category
                }));
            } else {
                setSelectedCategories((prevState: any) => {
                    const { [id]: undefined, ...rest } = prevState;
    
                    return rest;
                });
            }
        };
```

What is wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Please, provide a full example of the code.

Comment: hm not related to issue but `undefined` seems confusing here: `const { [id]: undefined, ...rest } = prevState;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to `console.log()` your states, right after your state setter is called, your state probably would not be updated by then because React sets the state asynchronously. `useEffect` can help you with that, you can `console.log()` your state every time it changes. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(search)
}, [search])
```

Comment: And what about the second state which is object? I think having it as a dep. will not be optimal

Comment: It would be okay. Using useEffect will not make any difference in terms of how your state is updated but it will help you to follow along better. By the way, do you have any other reason to think that state updates somehow problematic? Because your code seems fine.